# Cocoa Touch: iPad table grid layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to build a iPad version of a iPhone application. The application has a section with  photos all organized in a album/event. On the iPhone version the albums are listed in a standard UITableView, but for the iPad version I think it should be done differently.

Here is a sample from Apple's Photos App where the albums/events are shown in a grid:
[image: Photo App]

How can I create a similar view in my storyboard? Is it done using a custom TableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good open-source project named "AQGridView" to do custom grids. It can help you. The project is [here on github](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

I hope it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you know other open-source projects than AQGridView?

Comment: I don't know other projects like that. :/ May be the Three20 launcher project can fit to your needs ? http://three20.info/showcase/launcher